# How to return std::wstring from C++ to C# using PInvoke without writing stringbuffer conversion

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

i have a class in Native C++ for which i need to create a wrapper in c# using PInvoke. I'm facing issues while returning std::wstring to string. Is there any Marshal methods or attributes provided by dotnet? I don't want to manually write char or byte conversions as like other answers.

Node.h

```
#ifndef MYAPI // defined export in preprocessor
#define MYAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


class MYAPI Node
{
public:
    Node();

    ~Node();

    inline std::wstring GetName() { return mName; }

    inline void SetName(const wchar_t* name) { mName = std::wstring(name); }

private:
    std::wstring mName;

};
```

//c extern methods for PInvoke

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    MYAPI const wchar_t* GetNodeName(NativeCore::Node* obj);

 #ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

in my Node.cpp

```
MYAPI const wchar_t * GetNodeName(NativeCore::Node* obj)
{
    if (obj != NULL)
        return obj->GetName().c_str();
    return NULL;
}
```

In my c# wrapper

UnManagedWrapper.cs

class UnMangedWrapper
    {

```
    [DllImport("NativeCore.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public static extern string GetNodeName(IntPtr ptr);

}
```

it is not converting the return type const wchar_t* to string when using the above conversion.  Is there any other method to convert std::wstring to string in this Pinvoke?

I don't to manually convert it by getting the string buffer as like below.

```
[DllImport( "my.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode )]
private static extern void GetMyString(StringBuffer str, int len);
public string GetMyStringMarshal()
{
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(255);
    GetMyString(buffer, buffer.Capacity);
    return buffer.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You have deep problems. The string you return is invalid as soon as the function returns. Further the pinvoke assumes it needs to be destroyed and calls CoTaskMemFree. It will all work if you allocate a character array with CoTaskMemAlloc and return that.

Comment: Further, there are other ways to solve the problem, and hundreds of posts here on this topic. Try some research next.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I couldn't find relevant answer any where. I would like to know if there is any simple MarshalAs attribute to convert it directly.

Comment: Search harder. No amount of MarshalAs helps you with the current design, but you can change the design. My initial comment stands regarding CoTaskMemFree. Do you understand that yet?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I couldn't understand your first comment. Can you please provide some links regarding that? Also,  answer from 'Thomas Flinkow' below, seems to be working for me if i use BSTR. will that create any memory problem?

Comment: Do you know what CoTaskMemAlloc and CoTaskMemFree are?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know. Need to learn

Comment: There's not much point in having the discussion if you haven't got the ground knowledge required to evaluate the options.

Comment: U could share knowledge right?. I guess thats t reason people use ts portal

Comment: You could just type those two function names into a search engine and read the docs. That's easier for me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for the hint. i explored that and it taken me to new area to explore. https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/returning-strings-from-a-c-api/

Comment: @S.FrankRicharrd as explained in the answer, using `BSTR`s as shown below does not lead to memory problems, since the `Marshal` class will handle deallocation of the `BSTR` for you. (Note that this is not the case if you were to call [`Marshal.PointerToStringBSTR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostringbstr?view=netframework-4.7.2) yourself.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Node.cpp` file, use [`SysAllocString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-sysallocstring) from `oleauto.h` (or include `Windows.h`) to allocate the string for you like this:

```
MYAPI BSTR GetNodeName(NativeCore::Node* obj)
{
    if (obj != NULL)
        return SysAllocString(obj->GetName().c_str());
    return NULL;
}
```

Then adjust your native method wrapper to use `UnmanagedType.BStr` instead of `UnmanagedType.LPWStr`:

```
class UnMangedWrapper 
{
    [DllImport("NativeCore.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public static extern string GetNodeName(IntPtr ptr);
}
```

Using `BSTR` has the advantage that you don't have to call into the unmanaged code twice (once for the buffer length and another time for the actual string content) and the marshaller can automatically take care of deallocating the unmanaged string.

Answer (score 0):

The return value is always a special case with p/invoke methods. Because you don't use a CLR compatible string allocator (=COM) on the native side, you should define your method like this:

```
[DllImport("NativeCore.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr GetNodeName(IntPtr ptr);
```

and call it like this:

```
var ptr = GetNodeName(whatever);
var str = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ptr); // unicode because you use wstring
```

Note this is only ok if the C string (or more generally whatever memory the returned pointer points to) is not deallocated on the native side when the called method returns. For example, if the `wstring` is defined locally somewhere in the method, it will be automatically deallocated on native call return (and a crash will most likely happen).

Or if you want to avoid that extra call on the .NET side, pass the string as an argument, and use the return value as an error code, as most Windows APIs do.

Comment: This is no good. The returned C string is invalid once the function returns.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Only if you presume the C string is allocated in the function itself, which doesn't seem to be the case in the question.

Comment: OK, you are correct, sorry

Comment: Still, it would be worth adding some text to the answer to make that requirement explicit, just in case somebody tries to use this approach when the DLL function uses a local string rather than one owned by the instance.